# Error: "sudo: command not found" when trying to use XAMPP

Tags: terminal, network, sudo, webserver, hosts

I am trying to use XAMPP to create a server on my MacBook. I'm following the tutorial here:

- https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-install-start-test-xampp-on-mac-osx.cfm

and I'm stuck on the bit where I'm required to put the command

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp security`

I get asked to input my password and then encounter the following error:

```
sudo: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp: command not found
```

Any help here please?

Comment: check out MAMP if you just need to create a local server and aren't tied to XAMP specifically https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Check if the file `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp` is present by running `ls -l /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp`.

Comment: Which specific version did you install? I just tried, and got an `XAMPP.app` installed into `/Applications`, not an `XAMPP` folder as the instructions imply.

Answer (score -1):

#### Idea #1

The error could be because it's attempting to run this command:

```
$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp
```

You may need to pass the entire command with single or double quotes to the `sudo` command like this:

```
$ sudo '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp security'
```

#### Idea #2

If the above isn't your issue then I'd suggest changing directories and running the command directly from there:

```
$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
$ sudo xampp security
```

#### Idea #3

If that still doesn't work, take a look at the contents of the `xamppfiles` directory using the `ls` command and verify that `xampp` is in fact a file in this subdirectory. It it's missing then one of your steps to install XAMPP was either skipped or failed.